# Getting errors when trying to run Pyflame inside Python script

Tags: python, profiling, popen

**The aim:** profiling a Python script with Pyflame in another Python script.

**The details:** code is run on a virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

1) To run the profiled script I'm using:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "python_script.py"])
```

2) Then I'm trying to attach Pyflame to the process (treat this line as a smoke test):

```
subprocess.Popen(["sudo pyflame -s 60 -r 0.0001 " + str(process.pid)],
                      shell=True)
```

**The problem:** Without `sudo` in the above statement I'm getting a `Failed to attach to PID ...: Operation not permitted` error.

With `sudo` I'm getting `Failed to locate libpython named libpython2.7.so`.

I would be grateful for any ideas regarding how to make statement 2) work, with or without `sudo`!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Pyflame will return the second error that you got if these conditions are met:

- You compiled Pyflame for Python 2.X.
- You try to profile a script running under a Python 3.X interpreter.

Take a look at the source code of Pyflame [here](https://github.com/uber/pyflame/blob/master/src/pyfrob.cc#L39) and [here](https://github.com/uber/pyflame/blob/master/src/aslr.cc#L26).
When you run Pyflame, it looks into the memory space of your interpreter and it tries to find *libpython2.7.so*. For a Python 3.X interpreter, the library is not there.

So I suggest that you try the following:

1. Run the following command. You'll confirm whether the library is properly loaded in your interpreter.

   `cat /proc/{YOUR_PID}/maps | grep libpython2.7`
2. If it's not, then consider the following:

   1. Maybe you profiled the wrong process (i.e. it's not a Python process).
   2. Maybe it's a Python 3.X process, in which case you'll need to re-compile Pyflame to target Python 3.X.

To target Python 3.X when compiling Pyflame, refer to the documentation. Hint: you'll need to change the call to *./configure* as follows:

```
./configure --with-python=python3
```

Besides, if you have trouble making *python3* recognized as a library in your environment, you'll need to symlink to the Python 3.X interpreter's executable. This is a bit out of scope, so you can check out my personal blog for more details (see the post "Using Uber's Pyflame and Logs to Tackle Scaling Issues"). Disclaimer: I'm the author of that post.

Comment: It was not Python 3, but it might have been another interpreter indeed (PyPy, I think). Thanks! I'm not working on that code anymore, but if I get somewhere near it, I'll try it out. (And maybe that answer helps someone else.)